# Form validation in nextjs frontend with laravel backend

Tags: laravel, forms, validation

I am trying to let a user register on the web site. I would like to show an related error under the input field when there is an empty input field. I would like to check the email against the MySQL database as well to see if the email is already taken. If the email is already taken, I would like to show the error saying 'Email already taken!' under the email input field instead of normal email error.

Do I handle all of these in the backend or frontend?

I provide my code below:

registration.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import logodark from '../../images/logodark.png'
import Image from 'next/legacy/image'
import { MdArrowRight } from 'react-icons/md';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import axios, { Axios } from 'axios';


const registration = () => {
    const router = useRouter()

    const [name, setname] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [cPassword, setCPassword] = useState('')

    // Error message starts here
    const [errname, setErrname] = useState('')
    const [errEmail, setErrEmail] = useState('')
    const [errPassword, setErrPassword] = useState('')
    const [errCPassword, setErrCPassword] = useState('')
    const [registrationError, setRegistrationError] = useState('');
    

    // Handle function starts here
    const handleName = (e) => {
        setname(e.target.value)
        setErrname('')
    }
    
    const handleEmail = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value)
        setErrEmail('')
    }

    const handlePassword = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value)
        setErrPassword('')
    }

    const handleCPassword = (e) => {
        setCPassword(e.target.value)
        setErrCPassword('')
    }
    
    // Email validation
    const emailValidation = (email) => {
        return String(email)
            .toLowerCase()
            .match(/^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/)
    }


    // Submit button 
    async function handleRegistration (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(!name) {
            setErrname('Enter your name')
        }

        if(!email) {
            setErrEmail('Enter your email')
        } else if(!emailValidation(email)) {
            setErrEmail('Enter a valid email')
        }

        if(!password) {
            setErrPassword('Enter your password')
        } else if(password.length < 6) {
            setErrPassword('Passwords must be at least 6 characters.')
        }

        if(!cPassword) {
            setErrCPassword('Confirm your password')
        } else if(cPassword !== password) {
            setErrCPassword('Password not matched')
        }

        if (errname || errEmail || errPassword || errCPassword) {
            return;
        }

            const formdata = new FormData()
            formdata.append('name', name)
            formdata.append('email', email)
            formdata.append('password', password)

            try {
                const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/registration', formdata)
                if(response.status === 200) {
                    router.push('/')
                } else {
                    setRegistrationError('Error registering.')
                }
            } catch(error) {
                console.error('Error during registration:', error);
                setRegistrationError('Error registering.');
            }
    }
    


  return (
    <div className='w-full'>
        <div className='w-full bg-gray-100 pb-10'>
            <form className='w-[370px] mx-auto flex flex-col items-center'>
                <div onClick={() => router.push('/')} className='my-5 cursor-pointer'>
                    <Image 
                        src={logodark}
                        width={150}
                        height={40}
                        objectFit='contain'
                    />    
                </div>
                
                <div className='w-full border border-zinc-200 p-6'>
                    <h2 className='font-medium text-3xl mb-4'>Create Account</h2>
                    <div className='flex flex-col gap-3'>
                        <div>
                            <p className='font-medium pb-1'>Your name</p>
                            <input 
                                onChange={handleName} 
                                value={name}
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder='First name and last name' 
                                className='border font-medium rounded-sm placeholder:font-normal placeholder:normal-case border-gray-400 px-2 py-1 w-full outline-none focus:drop-shadow-md'
                            />
                            {errname && (
                                <p className='text-red-500 text-sm font-semibold pt-1'>
                                    <span className='italic mr-1'>!</span> 
                                    {errname}
                                </p>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className='font-medium pb-1'>Email or mobile phone number</p>
                            <input 
                                onChange={handleEmail}
                                value={email}
                                type="email" 
                                className='border font-medium lowercase rounded-sm border-gray-400 px-2 py-1 w-full outline-none focus:drop-shadow-md'
                            />
                            {errEmail && (
                                <p className='text-red-500 text-sm font-semibold pt-1'>
                                    <span className='italic mr-1'>!</span> 
                                    {errEmail}
                                </p>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className='font-medium pb-1'>Password</p>
                            <input
                                onChange={handlePassword}
                                value={password}
                                type="password"
                                placeholder='At least 6 characters.'
                                className='border rounded-sm placeholder:normal-case border-gray-400 px-2 py-1 w-full outline-none focus:drop-shadow-md' 
                            />
                            {errPassword && (
                                <p className='text-red-500 text-sm font-semibold pt-1'>
                                    <span className='italic mr-1'>!</span> 
                                    {errPassword}
                                </p>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className='font-medium pb-1'>Re-enter Password</p>
                            <input
                                onChange={handleCPassword}
                                value={cPassword}
                                type="password"
                                className='border rounded-sm border-gray-400 px-2 py-1 w-full outline-none focus:drop-shadow-md' 
                            />
                            {errCPassword && (
                                <p className='text-red-500 text-sm font-semibold pt-1'>
                                    <span className='italic mr-1'>!</span> 
                                    {errCPassword}
                                </p>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p className='text-sm text-gray-600 mt-2 mb-4'>Passwords must be at least 6 characters.</p>
                    <button
                        onClick={handleRegistration}
                        className='button border text-[17px] font-medium w-full mb-2'>Continue
                    </button>

                    {registrationError && (
                        <div>
                            {errname || errEmail || errPassword || errCPassword ? (
                                null
                            ) : <p className='text-red-500 text-sm font-semibold pt-1'>
                            <span className='italic mr-1'>!</span> {registrationError}
                                </p>}
                        </div>
                    )}
                    <div className='text-xs mt-2'>
                        <p 
                            className='mb-4'>By Continuing, you agree to Amazozn's 
                            <span className='text-blue-600 cursor-pointer hover:underline'> Conditions of Use</span> and 
                            <span className='text-blue-600 cursor-pointer hover:underline'> Privacy Notice</span>.
                        </p>
                        <p 
                            className='flex flex-row'>Already have an account? 
                            <span onClick={() => router.push('/signin')} className='flex items-center justify-center pl-1 cursor-pointer text-blue-600 hover:underline hover:text-red-600'>Sign in 
                                <span className='pt-0.5'><MdArrowRight /></span>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p 
                            className='flex flex-row'>Buying for work? 
                            <span className='flex items-center justify-center pl-1 cursor-pointer text-blue-600 hover:underline hover:text-red-600'>Create a few business account 
                                <span className='pt-0.5'><MdArrowRight /></span>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div className='w-full bg-gradient-to-t from-white via-white to-zinc-200'>
            <div className='w-[350px] mx-auto py-9 text-xs text-center'>
                <div className='flex items-center justify-center space-x-9 pb-1'>
                    <p className='text-blue-600 cursor-pointer hover:underline hover:text-red-600'>Conditions of Use</p>
                    <p className='text-blue-600 cursor-pointer hover:underline hover:text-red-600'>Privacy Notice</p>
                    <p className='text-blue-600 cursor-pointer hover:underline hover:text-red-600'>Privacy Policy</p>
                </div>
                <p className=''>© 1996-2023, ReactBd.com, Inc. or its affiliates</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default registration
```

api.php

```
Route::post('/registration', [UserController::class, 'registration']);
```

UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function registration(Request $request) {

        // Check if the email is already taken
        $existinguser = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if($existinguser) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Email already taken'], 400);
        }
        
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'User created successfully'], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Do I handle all of these in the backend or frontend?"*  - That comes down to opinion. You can handle it on both, or just the frontend, or just the backend. I'd recommend both (for redundancy) or backend only (since frontend can be manipulated), but either way, I'd recommend looking at Laravel's validation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation. You'd be able to define your Rules, then do `request()->validate()`, which _should_ automatically return an `HTTP 422` with each of your errors as `JSON`, which you could then parse and display on the frontend.

Comment: Also, using a bunch of individual states for each error message doesn't feel right... It works for sure, but you could also do `const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})`, then have a key/value Object for each error, like `{'name': 'The Name field is required.', 'email': 'The Email field must be a valid email address.'}`, etc. (this is how Laravel should return them if using its built-in validation). Displaying them would be as simple as `typeof errors.name !== 'undefined' && <p>{errors.name}</p>`, or similar. Less repetition of your code too 

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using laravel/nextjs I'm using react hook form and validation with yup
So I've created a custom function and I call it when there's api call error

```
const backendErrorHandler = (setError,backendErrors) => {
const formErrors = {};

for (const field in backendErrors) {
  // Assuming you're using useForm's setError function here
  // Replace 'setError' with the actual function you're using
  setError(field, {
    type: 'manual',
    message: backendErrors[field][0], // Assuming there's only one error message per field
  });

  formErrors[field] = backendErrors[field][0];
}

return formErrors;


};

  export default backendErrorHandler
```

Im passing [setError](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/seterror) function from react hook form as first argument, and the second one is the errors object
For example

```
catch(error){
   BackendErrorHandler(setError, error.response.data
}
```